# Consequences of changing names of tables and views in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, pivot-table

In our small business we are thinking about standardizing and restructuring our database, starting with the names.

The problem is that these tables and views are used in a lot of our pivot tables in Excel spreadsheets. My question is what consequences does the name changing in SQL Server have for Excel? Do we have to remake or update our connections in the pivot tables?

Comment: If the spreadsheets are wired directly to the SQL Server instance, then yes you'll have to change the table/database names there as well.

Comment: What are the consequences? That's a big vague. If you rename an object, any objects that reference it will need to be updated accordingly. Any external applications that reference those objects will also need to be updated. Applications and SQL Server won't "automagically" detect the new name of the object and simply use that one; you have to give it to new name.

Comment: If its a simple rename have you considered using synonyms?

Comment: This is one area that I feel that applications using Stored Procedures to deal with the Data Engine has a massive benefit. If you need to rename the names of the objects, you only need to update the Stored Procedures on the SQL Server (provided they themselves have no been renamed as well). This could mean that the application itself doesn't need to be updated at all, as the `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc, statements are all handled by the SPs on the server. Something that can save a lot of time; as you don't need to update, build, deploy and redistribute the application to all it's users.

Answer (score 4):

One semi-reasonable approach is to rename your tables and then to create new views using the old names<sup>1</sup> that just select from the newly-named table. (And similarly for renaming views). You would do this as a form of "interim" arrangement with an agreed upon date when these replacement views will be removed from the schema.

This allows you to progressively work to update the spreadsheets over a longer period of time, and should not invalidate their queries.

---

(In general, you should be able to replace a table with a view or a view with a table and not invalidate queries. This is trickier to achieve in practice if the queries you need to support include INSERT, UPDATE or DELETEs since triggers may then be required on the view)

---

<sup>1</sup>Or as Andrew suggests in the comments, using Synonyms. But that will only work if its only the table names changing, not column names.

Comment: One thing to note about views is if you have query hints on queries using those tables, not all hints will be pushed through a view. Index hints are particularly problematic. Synonyms will allow hints to be pushed through - rare scenario but in some situations compelling.

Answer (score 2):

You are faced with a problem.  Obviously, if you change the names of the tables in the database, then you will break outside applications (such as Excel) that use those names.

Recommendation?  Change the application logic to use *views* instead of tables.  Then you can change the table structure to do what you want, adjusting the views to reflect the new data structure.

Note that you can have other problems as well within the database, particularly if you use dynamic SQL.